# Select all files in folder containing 'x' in the filename

Tags: python-3.x

This gets me all files in a folder, how do i filter them for files containing 'x' in their filenames?

```
import os

directory_path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

files = os.listdir(directory_path)
```

Comment: all files in the `x` folder only or even in it's sub folders ?

Comment: only the files in directory_path @ChihebNexus